# Delphi: TAdoTable.Insert not really an Insert?

Tags: delphi, tadotable

I have two ADO Tables linked as master/details tables, tblCategory (master) and tblItems (details). Both tables have its own grid, and displayed in the same form. I also have data aware controls (dbedits).

Say, currently I'm at: Category=Books, No of Items=10 records, and pointing at record number 5 in the grid. I want to add a new record to the item, so I use:

tblItems.Insert;

The problem is, instead of adding a new row, the grid and the db aware controls are showing the current record (rec No 5). Not inly that, it seems the record is in edit mode too. After I cancel it and repeat the Insert command, only then the new row appeared.

How to fix this, so each time I use tblItems.Insert it always add a new and empty row :)

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, I think I know what caused it. It's the db aware controls. After the insert command, user will input data. This makes the db aware control receives focus and it automatically sets its position to the current record and displays it.

The solution is to use non-db-aware controls instead, and set the behavior programatically

Comment: You can select your answer as the accepted answer; just click on the check mark on the left.